# Why my code show the efficiency of 'for-loop' is higher than that of 'comprehension'?

Tags: python, for-loop

Why my code show the efficiency of 'for-loop' is higher than that of 'comprehension'?

```
# CODE-1:

import time                      
start_time = time.time()          
for i in range(10000000):
    1
end_time = time.time()             
run_time = end_time - start_time   
print('run_time1: ', run_time)


# CODE-2
start_time = time.time()          
[1 for i in range(10000000)]
end_time = time.time()             
run_time = end_time - start_time  
print('run_time2: ', run_time)

# The results:
(1) run_time1:  0.5030415058135986
(2) run_time2:  1.1129977703094482
```

Comment: Because building a warehouse and then delivering 10 million boxes into it takes longer than just delivering 10 million boxes

Answer (score 2):

Difference is with `comprehension` you are creating list, with `for-loop` you are only calling `1` which in is atmost only some mathematical expression

```
for i in range(10000000):
    1 # calling `1`, only expression

[1 for i in range(10000000)] # this creates list so there is more things to do than in first example
```

Answer (score 2):

While neither of these snippets does anything useful (they have no side effects and do not return anything), the second version actually has to construct a `list` object, which drags its performance down. Run in Python 3.7+:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('''for i in range(10000000): 1''')
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              16 (to 18)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (10000000)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 16)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (i)
             14 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   16 POP_BLOCK
        >>   18 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('''[1 for i in range(10000000)]''')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f974a725db0, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (10000000)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7f974a725db0, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 14)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
             10 LIST_APPEND              2
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that the `listcomp` object does much more than the first loop: BUILD_LIST and LIST_APPEND on every iteration.

Comment: I know it's an overkill to use `dis` here, but I really wanted to see what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

As others explained, your loop does not build a list so it is faster. An appropriate comparision should be like the following.

Loop:

```
l = []
for i in range(10000000):
    l.append(1)
```

List comprehension:

```
l = [1 for i in range(10000000)]
```